# Choose between datatypes and call matching methods?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
if (a==true) 
{
    dbA objectInstance = new dbA();
}
else
{
    dbB objectInstance = new dbB();
}

objectInstance.Name = "New name";
```

I get "the name objectInstance does not exist in the current context", I assume because the def happens inside the conditional.

There must be a better pattern to do this - should I have dbA and dbB inherit from the same class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `dbA` and `dbB` would need a common base class or interface and that base class or interface would need to have the `Name` property as part of its public contract.

Then you could do this:

```
SomeBase objectInstance;

if (a==true) 
{
    objectInstance = new dbA();
}
else
{
    objectInstance = new dbB();
}

objectInstance.Name = "New name";
```

That being said I think an interface is your best choice here unless these types already share a base class.

Comment: No need to assign to null to start with - indeed, I *wouldn't* to make it clear it'll definitely be assigned in one of the conditions.

Comment: You are right!  I wasn't near a compiler so I couldn't remember if the compiler would complain about the unassigned variable. :)